# Please, can someone provide me all language tags available in dbpedia like @en @fr @de?

Tags: tags, dbpedia

the title says all of my question... i searched in google but didnt find any list... ie i tried @HE or @YI for hebrew without success.

here is my working arraylist of language in xml array

```
<!-- String Array Languages-->
    <string-array name="array_language">
        <item>EN</item>
        <item>DE</item>
        <item>FR</item>
        <item>ES</item>
        <item>PT</item>
        <item>IT</item>
        <item>NL</item>
        <item>PL</item>
        <item>JA</item>
        <item>ZH</item>
        <item>RU</item>
        <item>AR</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: for the guy who downvoted, please explain why? and why you dont provide me an answer if you find the question stupid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest way I can see of getting this data. Of course it takes a while to be executed. However this only looks at the `rdfs:label`, if other tags such as `dbpedia-owl:abstract` or `rdfs:comment` have different languages, it might be worth checking and comparing.

```
SELECT distinct ?language
WHERE { ?x rdfs:label ?label .
     BIND (lang(?label) AS ?language )
}
```